# Does go GC keep whole objects in memory, while interior pointer to one field remains? Can this cause memory leaks?

Tags: go, memory-leaks

Does go's GC keep whole objects in memory, while interior pointer to a field remains?

Can this cause memory leaks, in a code like this? Or is go's GC "smart enough" to notice that the rest of the object is no longer needed and clear it from memory?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

const aLot = 500000000

func getInteriorPointer() *int {
    type bigStruct struct {
        someBigThing [aLot]int
        smallThing   int
    }
    b := bigStruct{smallThing: 3}
    return &b.smallThing
}

func main() {
    p := getInteriorPointer()
    // keep using p in the rest of the app, 
    // never using someBigThing from the struct
    fmt.Println(*p)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Memory will be kept until there is no longer any reference to any part of the allocation.

The usual example is given in slice tricks

> [SliceTricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks)
>
> Delete without preserving order
>
> ```
> a[i] = a[len(a)-1] 
> a = a[:len(a)-1]
> ```
>
> NOTE If the type of the element is a pointer or a struct with pointer
>   fields, which need to be garbage collected, the above implementations
>   of Cut and Delete have a potential memory leak problem: some elements
>   with values are still referenced by slice a and thus can not be
>   collected.

Comment: I knew about this slice issue, but I didn't know it's an issue with interior pointers in general. :)

Comment: Note, however, that a pointer to a struct field is pretty rare, and this "leak" would not apply to cases where e.g. you return a field of a struct, and the field is of a pointer type (because the pointer would be copied and the memory referenced by it is independent of the struct allocation).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at profiler, it seems to indeed be a memory leak (go1.11.5 darwin/amd64)

---

Let's look at profiler.

I found [an online example for debugging memory](https://play.golang.org/p/CHd8wCf5oP). By adapting to my example, I did this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "runtime/debug"
    "runtime/pprof"
)

const aLot = 5000000

func getInteriorPointer() *int {
    type bigStruct struct {
        someBigThing [aLot]int
        smallThing   int
    }
    b := bigStruct{smallThing: 3}
    return &b.smallThing
}

func main() {
    p := getInteriorPointer()
    runtime.GC()
    debug.FreeOSMemory()
    fmem, _ := os.Create("prof.prof")
    pprof.WriteHeapProfile(fmem)

    // keep using p in the rest of the app,
    // never using someBigThing from the struct
    fmt.Println(*p)
}
```

Now I run `go tool pprof prof.prof` and `list main`

```
ROUTINE ======================== main.getInteriorPointer in /Users/karel/exp/exp.go
   38.15MB    38.15MB (flat, cum)   100% of Total
         .          .     13:func getInteriorPointer() *int {
         .          .     14:   type bigStruct struct {
         .          .     15:           someBigThing [aLot]int
         .          .     16:           smallThing   int
         .          .     17:   }
   38.15MB    38.15MB     18:   b := bigStruct{smallThing: 3}
         .          .     19:   return &b.smallThing
         .          .     20:}
         .          .     21:
         .          .     22:func main() {
         .          .     23:   p := getInteriorPointer()
ROUTINE ======================== main.main in /Users/karel/exp/exp.go
         0    38.15MB (flat, cum)   100% of Total
         .          .     18:   b := bigStruct{smallThing: 3}
         .          .     19:   return &b.smallThing
         .          .     20:}
         .          .     21:
         .          .     22:func main() {
         .    38.15MB     23:   p := getInteriorPointer()
         .          .     24:   runtime.GC()
         .          .     25:   debug.FreeOSMemory()
         .          .     26:   fmem, _ := os.Create("prof.prof")
         .          .     27:   pprof.WriteHeapProfile(fmem)
         .          .     28:
```

It seems garbage collector indeed doesn't remove the unnecessary object from memory. *If* I understand the format correctly. (I might not, since there is almost no documentation.)